# Is Panthon Files from Loki version installable for Freya?

Tags: pantheon-files, release-loki

In [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/5499/170) it is confirmed the possibility of using a development version of Files (the one that should be default in Loki).

Can I install that in Freya?

Comment: Have you tried my answer yet (and upvote if it does work)

Comment: @SuiciDoga - I think I will try it in the end. I was about to consider if I really need it. Could you also add the ppa details to your answer? (link and/or commands)

Comment: I have added the commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to install the latest Pantheon Files if you add the daily PPA , upgrade Pantheon Files and remove the daily PPA. During the process do not attempt to update elementary OS since it would break

> WARNING : You are installing development packages so they may be
>   unstable and break your system.

### To install run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
```

### To downgrade to the old version

```
sudo apt-get remove pantheon-files
sudo apt-get remove libpantheon-files-core0
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```

### Screenshot

[image: Pantheon Files]

As you can see the thumbnails aren't working so I downgraded to the old version.

#### UPDATE : I have tested it on my laptop and it works.